# Limit distribution of Markov Chain

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

[image]

I have to determine the limiting distribution for the MC
so I determine the equations first:

$\Pi_0 +\Pi_1 + \Pi_2 + \Pi_3 +\Pi_4 =1$

$\Pi_0 = \Pi_0q + \Pi_1q + \Pi_2q +\Pi_3q +\Pi_4$

$\Pi_1 = \Pi_0p$

$\Pi_2 = \Pi_1p$

$\Pi_3 = \Pi_2p$

$\Pi_4 = \Pi_3p$

and then I tried to solve the system and I got this:

$0= \Pi_0 (-1+q+pq+p^2q+p^3q+p^4) $

So I conclude $0= \Pi_0$ therefore $\Pi_1 = \Pi_2 = \Pi_3 =\Pi_4 =0$

but this doesn't match the answer of the book.

Can somebody tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: sum of all the $\Pi_i$'s do not add to one

Comment: Are you looking for some vector $ \pi$ st $P\pi=\pi$? The first equation requiring that the sum of entries in $\pi $ be equal to 1 is correct, but how did you come up with the other equations?

Comment: @Any I substitute $ \Pi_0$ in the other equations, that's just algebra

Comment: @Any, for stationary distributions you look for _left_ eigenvectors $\pi P = \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Markov chain, you need find the vector ${\bf \Pi}$ that satisfies the following:

$$ \bf \Pi\ {\bf{P}} = \Pi$$

To start, compute $\bf\Pi\ P$, and we get

$$
{\bf\Pi\ P} = \left[\Pi _5+\Pi _1 q+\Pi _2 q+\Pi _3 q+\Pi _4 q,\ p \Pi _1,\ p \Pi _2,\ p \Pi _3,\ p \Pi _4\right].
$$

Then we set up the linear equations, as shown below:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Pi _5+\Pi _1 q+\Pi _2 q+\Pi _3 q+\Pi _4 q & = & \Pi _1 \\
p \Pi _1 & =& \Pi _2 \\
p \Pi _2 & =&\Pi _3 \\
p \Pi _3& = &\Pi _4 \\
\Pi _1+\Pi _2+\Pi _3+\Pi _4+\Pi _5& =& 1
\end{eqnarray}
$$

An then once we solve them, we get:

$$\Pi _1 = -\frac{1}{p \left(p^2+p+1\right) (q-1)+q-2}$$

$$\Pi _2=-\frac{p}{p \left(p^2+p+1\right) (q-1)+q-2}$$

$$\Pi _3 = -\frac{p^2}{p \left(p^2+p+1\right) (q-1)+q-2}$$

$$\Pi _4= -\frac{p^3}{p \left(p^2+p+1\right) (q-1)+q-2}$$

$$\Pi _5= -\frac{p^4}{p \left(p^2+p+1\right) (q-1)+q-2}$$

Comment: $\Pi _i$ shouldn't have (-1) sign?

Comment: No. You don't want to multiply by (-1) sign. The answer above is correct. It's just the way I computed the ss probabilities. Try to compute the $\bf \Pi$ vector with $p=0.3, q=0.7$. You will get $\Pi=[0.360607, 0.252425, 0.176698, 0.123688, 0.0865818]$, which satisfies $\bf \Pi\ {\bf{P}} = \Pi$. Play around with other values of $p$ and $q$ such that $p + q=1$ to compute other $\bf \Pi$ vectors to see that  $\bf \Pi\ {\bf{P}} = \Pi$ to verify the results for yourself.

Comment: so this is the stationary distribution, why the book asked for limiting distribution then? it was a mistake?

Comment: The "limiting distribution" and the "stationary distribution" are the same thing FYI. It's different names for the same thing.

Comment: no, it's not the same. check karlin & taylor book's definition and you'll see. forget it, I think you're correct. sorry

Comment: Hmm...My understanding is a stationary distribution is one that is stable over time. As far as I'm aware, the limiting distribution of a Markov chain is stationary and if a Markov chain has a stationary distribution it is also a limiting distribution.

Comment: Given Karlin's text (An Introduction to Stochastic Modeling by Pinsky and Karlin (2011)), here is my understanding. With this definition of stationarity, the statement on page 168 can be retroactively restated as:
The limiting distribution of a regular Markov chain is a stationary distribution. If the limiting distribution of a Markov chain is a stationary distribution, then the stationary distribution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

You were correct in your setup, and getting to $$0= \Pi_0 (-1+q+pq+p^2q+p^3q+p^4).$$

However, you need to use the fact that $p+q=1$ to rewrite this.  You get
\begin{align*}
-1+q+pq+p^2q+p^3q+p^4 &= -p+pq+p^2q+p^3q+p^4\\
&=p(q-1)+p^2q+p^3q+p^4\\
&=-p^{2}+p^2q+p^3q+p^4\\
&=p^{2}(q-1)+p^3q+p^4\\
&=-p^{3}+p^3q+p^4\\
&=p^{3}(q-1) + p^{4}\\
&=-p^{4}+p^{4}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Hence, we can choose any non-zero value for $\Pi_{0}$ and normalize later.  By normalize I mean enforce the condition that $\Pi_0 +\Pi_1 + \Pi_2 + \Pi_3 +\Pi_4 =1.$  Without this condition we are simply finding a left eigenvector for $P$ corresponding to an eigenvalue of $1$.  Choosing $\Pi_{0} = 1$ we get
\begin{align*}
\Pi_{0}&=1\\
\Pi_{1}&=p\\
\Pi_{2}&=p^{2}\\
\Pi_{3}&=p^{3}\\
\Pi_{4}&=p^{4}.
\end{align*}

Note that we now have a vector $\Pi$ such that $\Pi P = \Pi$, however $\Pi$ as it is now is not a probability vector because we relaxed the condition that $\Pi_0 +\Pi_1 + \Pi_2 + \Pi_3 +\Pi_4 =1.$  To normalize $\Pi$ so it satisfies this condition, we divide $\Pi$ by the sum of its components so that the resulting vector is a probability vector.  Since currently $\Pi_0 +\Pi_1 + \Pi_2 + \Pi_3 +\Pi_4 =1 + p + p^{2} + p^{3} + p^{4}$, we divide each component of $\Pi$ by this to obtain the limiting distribution (which I'm also calling $\Pi$):

\begin{align*}
\Pi_{0}&=\frac{1}{1+p+p^{2}+p^{3}+p^{4}}\\
\Pi_{1}&=\frac{p}{1+p+p^{2}+p^{3}+p^{4}}\\
\Pi_{2}&=\frac{p^{2}}{1+p+p^{2}+p^{3}+p^{4}}\\
\Pi_{3}&=\frac{p^{3}}{1+p+p^{2}+p^{3}+p^{4}}\\
\Pi_{4}&=\frac{p^{4}}{1+p+p^{2}+p^{3}+p^{4}}.
\end{align*}

This division didn't change the fact that $\Pi P = \Pi$, but now if we add the components we get $1$ which solves the system of equations.

Comment: how do you normalize?

Comment: Divide by the sum of the components of the unnormalized vector so that the components of the new vector sum to one.

Comment: and why do we do that?

Comment: I thought the way of solution of this problems is solving the system of equations

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit.  We are solving the system of equations, but it's simpler if you temporarily relax the condition that the components sum to $1$ and then enforce it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, i was a little bit difficult to understand at first but thank you.